# native message response extension chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I use this code

```
// background.js
chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage( "com.example.native",
  { text: "test" },
  function(response) {
    console.log("Received " + response);
});
```

C# code

```
private static void OpenStandardStreamOut(string stringData)
{
    string msgdata =  "{\"text\":\"" + stringData + "\"}";
    int DataLength = msgdata.Length;
    Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
    stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 0) & 0xFF));
    stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 8) & 0xFF));
    stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 16) & 0xFF));
    stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 24) & 0xFF));
    Console.Write(msgdata);
}

private static List<LoginPack> OpenStandardStreamIn()
{
    Stream stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput();
    int length = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    stdin.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
    length = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
    string input = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        input += (char)stdin.ReadByte();
    }
    JObject Read=(JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(input);
    //string dataPackStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Read);
    Chrome chromeClass = new Chrome();
    List<LoginPack> lp = new List<LoginPack>();
    if (Read!=null)
        if (Read.Count != 0)
            lp = chromeClass.getInfoFromChrome(Read["text"].ToString());
    if (lp.Count == 0)
        return null;
    return lp;
}
```

//class chrome

```
public class Chrome
{
    public class Data
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public List<LoginPack> getInfoFromChrome(string colName)
    {
        try
        {
            // string filename = "my_chrome_passwords.html";
            //  StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(filename, false, Encoding.UTF8);
            string db_way = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
                + "/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 1/Login Data1";
            Console.WriteLine("DB file = " + db_way);
            string db_field = "logins";
            List<LoginPack> lp = new List<LoginPack>();
            byte[] entropy = null;
            string description;
            string ConnectionString = "data source=" + db_way + ";New=True;UseUTF16Encoding=True";
            DataTable DB = new DataTable();
            string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} where action_url=\"{1}\" or origin_url=\"{2}\"", db_field, colName, colName);
            // System.IO.StreamWriter file1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
            // file1.WriteLine(sql);
            // file1.Close();
            using (SQLiteConnection connect = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connect);
                SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(DB);
                int rows = DB.Rows.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    byte[] byteArray = (byte[])DB.Rows[i][5];
                    byte[] decrypted = DPAPI.Decrypt(byteArray, entropy, out description);
                    lp.Add(new LoginPack { userNameElement = (string)DB.Rows[i][2], userName = (string)DB.Rows[i][3], passElement = (string)DB.Rows[i][4], pass = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetString(decrypted) });
                    //System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test2.txt");
                    //file.WriteLine(lp[i].userName);
                    //file.Close();
                }
            }
            // Writer.Close();
            return lp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            ex = ex.InnerException;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Application(C#) give data from extension but Extension cant get any response from app
if I use `OpenStandardStreamOut` function at first(in C# app) then Extension can get response from it 
what's the problem?

Comment: I've read your question like twenty times but still not sure what exactly happens there. FYI Native apps are executed by Chrome with redirected input and output streams when the extension opens the port so the extension is always an initiator of communication.

Comment: Actualy, Extension dont recieve data from application(C#) after postMessage

Comment: In that case you need to show how you receive the data from your extension. The code you posted doesn't have that part.

Comment: ok ,I put OpenStandardStreamIn function

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what the problem is. Just in case I'll repeat: your native app can't be an initiator because it's started by Chrome when your extension invokes runtime.connectNative. Also, messaging is asynchronous but your code seems to expect synchronous response. You can find examples of Native Messaging in C# and adapt them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your 'Chrome' class is working badly. Check that again and make sure to use Standard Streams instead of your third party Streams. Also remove `Console.WriteLine("DB file = " + db_way);` line and try again.